# Problema em passar informações do AJAX para o Controller

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

Tenho o ajax a seguir que pega o código do pedido. Até o momento consigo pegar o código do pedido, porém envia como null ao `controller`

```
var btn = document.getElementById("btnNumeroPed");
            btn.onclick = function () {
                var dataJson = JSON.stringify({ "PedNumero": $("#inputNumero").val() });
                //var dataJson = JSON.stringify({ "clientes": data });
                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "/Loja/ListarPedidos?PedNumero=" + $("#inputNumero").val(),
                    data: dataJson,
                    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                    dataType: "json",
                    async: false,
                    success: function (data) {
                        if (data > 0) {
                            $("#txtCodigoProduto").val(data.itPNumero);
                            $("#txtDescProduto").val(data.itPDescrProd);
                            $("#txtQtdeProduto").val(data.itPQtde);
                            $("#txtPontos").val(data.itPPontos);
                            $("#txtPreco").val(data.itPrecoComp);
                            $("#txtDesconto").val(data.itPDesconto);
                            $("#txtTotal").val(data.itPTotal);
                        }
                    }
                });

            }
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Código:

```
public List<Models.PedidoVendaItens> ListarPedidos(string codigo)
        {
            try
            {
                Models.PedidoVendaItens objItens = new Models.PedidoVendaItens(config)
                {
                    ItPNumero = codigo
                };
                return new Models.PedidoVendaItens(config).ListarItensPedido(codigo);

            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {

                throw ex;
            }

        }
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Para enviar um tipo primitivo por post, deve realizar uma pequena gambiarra (que inclusive é documentada).

**1ª Opção** - enviar um JSON com a propriedade vazia.:

```
curl -X POST "http://localhost:xpto/api/Loja/ListarPedidos" -H "accept: application/json" -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d '{ "": "00000027" }'
```

**2ª Opção** - adicionar um `=` antes do valor a ser enviado.:

```
curl -X POST "http://localhost:xpto/api/Loja/ListarPedidos" -H "accept: application/json" -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d "=00000027"
```

Ou então modifique a assinatura do seu método para receber este dado por QueryString

```
public List<Models.PedidoVendaItens> ListarPedidos([FromQuery] codigo)
```

Então faça a seguinte chamada

```
curl -X POST "http://localhost:xpto/api/Loja/ListarPedidos?codigo=00000027" -H "accept: application/json"
```